# get multidimensional array in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

```
Array
(
    [return] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [test] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [error_row] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
        )

)
```

How can I get the `test` in `[error_row]` using `foreach` loop? Already tried this [multidimensional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413589/php-foreach-with-multidimensional-array) and also this [multidimensional2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901786/how-to-display-multi-dimensional-array-using-foreach) but get no answer it those two question.

Comment: @nfnneil I tried the answer in link but still dont get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simple one is `$array['error_row'][0];`

if you want to use foreach

```
$result = '';
foreach($array as $k => $v)
{
  if($k == 'error_row');
  $result = $v[0];
}
```

Comment: in top of this foreach($array as $k => $v) im not going to foreach? like `foreach($a as $arr => $array){ foreach($array as $k => $v){ // code here } }`